# chef SSL Validation failure connecting to host after Chef Development Kit installation

Tags: chef-infra

I ran knife bootstrap on a node with, chef client ran and everything works.

After I installed on the node Chef Development Kit:

```
wget https://packages.chef.io/stable/el/7/chefdk-0.15.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh chefdk-0.15.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Chef client versions:

Before the chefdk installation: starting Chef Client, version 11.8.2

After the chefdk installation: starting Chef Client, version 12.11.18

The error message:

```
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: xxx.mychefserver.mydomain.com - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
================================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "xxx.mychefnode.mydomain.com"
================================================================================
Unexpected Error:
-----------------
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL Error connecting to https://xxx.mychefserver.mydomain.int/nodes/xxx.mychefnode.mydomain.com - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

Any idea how to fix it ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Chef Server generates a self-signed certificate for HTTPS. You can add this to Chef's trust root by running `knife ssl fetch`. You can also install a "real" (i.e. public trust) certificate on the Chef Server. The latter is preferred when possible.

Comment: I think the issue is with chef client 12 on the node and Chef server 11, I tried a almost everything with SSL, nothing works.

Comment: Nope @Alex Brickmann, that's not the problem. Those are compatible and I also run it in an environment in this constellation. @coderanger is right. Have you really tried `knife ssl fetch`?

Comment: I mean chef client 12 with chef server 11 and self sign certificate, yes I tried, it just download some certificates but its not help, there is no errors with public trust certificate,  do you know how to install Chef Development Kit without chef-client upgrade automatically to version 12 ?

Comment: Yes, that works fine overall. Your TLS issues are not related to Chef versions in any way.